# Run-time exception expects parameter '@OE_ID', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord
@OE_ID  varchar(11)
AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM [EOEMS].[dbo].[tblOfficeEquipmentProfile]
WHERE [OE_ID]=@OE_ID
END
RETURN
GO


  Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
  sqlconn.Open()
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "oeq-su-001")
  cmd.Parameters("@OE_ID").Value = "oeq-su-001"
  cmd.CommandText = "DeletetblOfficeEquipmentProfileRecord"
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  sqlconn.Close()
```

Come up with the new code, `oeq-su-001` is one of the example of `OE_ID` in my database.

Answer (score 0):

SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType, int) creates an SqlParameter with no value and a default direction of "input".
Parameters.Add(SqlParameter) adds the parameter to the collection.

You can either use [Parameters.Add(string, SqlDbType, int, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5xwx8sc.aspx) or set the value before calling ExecuteNonQuery.

e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "123")

cmd.Parameters("@OE_ID").Value = "123"
```

Comment: come up with the new code, 'oeq-su-001' is one of the example of OE_ID in my database

Comment: Do you mean you are still getting the error? Move the .CommandText line right under the .CommandType line.

Comment: it does not return error, but it does not delete records on the database

Comment: sir your "123" is just an example of what could be the OE_ID in the database right? so i can put anything there as long as its varchar type like "oeq-su-001" ????

Comment: Yes. Your error is likely in the SP itself. Do you know how to profile? What is the text of the SP?

Comment: sir here is my stored procedure.